# How to show ExtJS button in different color when it is clicked

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'form',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                pack: 'center',
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 800,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                margin: '10 10 10 10',
                text: 'today',
                ui:'default-toolbar',
                handler: function() {
                    Ext.getCmp("new").show();
                    Ext.getCmp("test").hide();
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                margin: '10 0 10 10',
                ui:'default-toolbar',
                text: 'last 7days',
                handler: function() {
                    Ext.getCmp("test").show();
                    Ext.getCmp("new").hide();
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                margin: '10 20 10 20',
                id: 'new',
                html: 'you have selcted today button',
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                margin: '10 20 10 20',
                id: 'test',
                html: 'you have selcted last 7days button',
                hidden: true
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you want multiple buttons of which one is selected. For this, you have to provide the same [`toggleGroup`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#cfg-toggleGroup) config to all buttons.

The toggled button is then displayed in a darker blue than the untoggled buttons. You may have to change the function from the `handler` config to `toggleHandler`.

Comment: can you provide any fiddle example thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',
launch: function () {
    Ext.create({
        xtype: 'form',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            pack: 'center',
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 800,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '10 10 10 10',
            text: 'today',
            ui:'default-toolbar',
            handler: function(btn) {
                var otherBtn = btn.up('form').down('button[text=last 7days]');
                btn.setStyle('background-color', '#08a4ff');
                otherBtn.setStyle('background-color', '#f6f6f6');
                Ext.getCmp("new").show();
                Ext.getCmp("test").hide();
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '10 0 10 10',
            ui:'default-toolbar',
            text: 'last 7days',
            handler: function(btn) {
                var otherBtn = btn.up('form').down('button[text=today]');
                btn.setStyle('background-color', '#08a4ff');
                otherBtn.setStyle('background-color', '#f6f6f6');
                Ext.getCmp("test").show();
                Ext.getCmp("new").hide();
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            margin: '10 20 10 20',
            id: 'new',
            html: 'you have selcted today button',
            hidden: true
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            margin: '10 20 10 20',
            id: 'test',
            html: 'you have selcted last 7days button',
            hidden: true
        }]
    });
}Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',
launch: function () {
    Ext.create({
        xtype: 'form',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            pack: 'center',
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 800,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '10 10 10 10',
            text: 'today',
            ui:'default-toolbar',
            handler: function(btn) {
                var otherBtn = btn.up('form').down('button[text=last 7days]');
                btn.setStyle('background-color', '#08a4ff');
                otherBtn.setStyle('background-color', '#f6f6f6');
                Ext.getCmp("new").show();
                Ext.getCmp("test").hide();
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            margin: '10 0 10 10',
            ui:'default-toolbar',
            text: 'last 7days',
            handler: function(btn) {
                var otherBtn = btn.up('form').down('button[text=today]');
                btn.setStyle('background-color', '#08a4ff');
                otherBtn.setStyle('background-color', '#f6f6f6');
                Ext.getCmp("test").show();
                Ext.getCmp("new").hide();
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            margin: '10 20 10 20',
            id: 'new',
            html: 'you have selcted today button',
            hidden: true
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            margin: '10 20 10 20',
            id: 'test',
            html: 'you have selcted last 7days button',
            hidden: true
        }]
    });
}
});
```

You also use css class for the code. Instead of using [setStyle](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#placeholder-setStyle), you can you [addClass](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#method-addCls)